# How to store a JSON string in a JSON object without causing syntax errors?

Tags: javascript, python, json

I have a JSON object, and in the field `resource_hours` I want to store a JSON string.

```
{
  "id": 4,
  "resource": 1,
  "resource_hours": "json goes here",
  "start": "2009-10-10",
  "end": "2010-10-10",
  "created_at": "2017-06-01T13:23:06.103867Z",
  "modified_at": "2017-06-01T13:23:06.103867Z"
}
```

Here is the string/object I want to store:

```
{
  "winner": "john",
  "loser": "not john"
}
```

I tried this:

```
"resource_hours": "{"winner":"john","loser":"not john"}"
```

but obviously that raised an error due to the overlapping double quotes.

I also tried using `\` to escape the quotes like so:

```
"resource_hours": "{\"winner\":\"john\",\"loser\":\"not john\"}"
```

This worked (no error was raised), but is it still a JSON string/object? Can it still be parsed as a JSON object if pulled from a database using an API?

Comment: `var obj = JSON.parse(<yourstring>)` and then `obj.resource_hours = <value>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSON.stringify` method allows you to convert object into a string:

```
const objectWillBeStoredInJson = {
  "winner": "john",
  "loser": "not john"
}

const object = {
  "id": 4,
  "resource": 1,
  "resource_hours": JSON.stringify(objectWillBeStoredInJson),
  "start": "2009-10-10",
  "end": "2010-10-10",
  "created_at": "2017-06-01T13:23:06.103867Z",
  "modified_at": "2017-06-01T13:23:06.103867Z"
}
```

Now, `object.resource_hours` has a string that refers to `objectWillBeStoredInJson` when parsed.

You can use `JSON.parse` when you want to access it:

```
const objectWillBeStoredInJson = JSON.parse(object.resource_hours)
```

Comment: Thank you for the Javascript solution!

Answer (score 2):

This will work for you using Python:

```
>>> import json
>>> j = {
... "id": 4,
... "resource": 1,
... "resource_hours": "json goes here",
... "start": "2009-10-10",
... "end": "2010-10-10",
... "created_at": "2017-06-01T13:23:06.103867Z",
... "modified_at": "2017-06-01T13:23:06.103867Z"
... }
>>> j
{'id': 4, 'resource': 1, 'resource_hours': 'json goes here', 'start': '2009-10-10', 'end': '2010-10-10', 'created_at': '
2017-06-01T13:23:06.103867Z', 'modified_at': '2017-06-01T13:23:06.103867Z'}

>>> # converting your data to json
>>> act_json = json.dumps(j)
>>> act_json
'{"id": 4, "resource": 1, "resource_hours": "json goes here", "start": "2009-10-10", "end": "2010-10-10", "created_at":
"2017-06-01T13:23:06.103867Z", "modified_at": "2017-06-01T13:23:06.103867Z"}'

>>> # value that needs to be added
>>> val_to_store = {
... "winner": "john",
... "loser": "not john"
... }

>>> # getting the data and converting it to dictionary
>>> j = json.loads(act_json)

>>> # assigning the values
>>> j['resource_hours'] = val_to_store
>>> j
{'id': 4, 'resource': 1, 'resource_hours': {'winner': 'john', 'loser': 'not john'}, 'start': '2009-10-10', 'end': '2010-
10-10', 'created_at': '2017-06-01T13:23:06.103867Z', 'modified_at': '2017-06-01T13:23:06.103867Z'}

>>> # converting back to json, if needed
>>> to_json = json.dumps(j)
>>> to_json
'{"id": 4, "resource": 1, "resource_hours": {"winner": "john", "loser": "not john"}, "start": "2009-10-10", "end": "2010
-10-10", "created_at": "2017-06-01T13:23:06.103867Z", "modified_at": "2017-06-01T13:23:06.103867Z"}'
```

Happy coding !!!

Comment: Thanks! Good Python solution.